# firestore orderby on subproperty (subcollection)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using the new firestore, I have a structure that looks like this:

```
{
    ...
    "username": "mr_jones",
    "date_created": 1508395138572,
    "stats": {
        "posts": 143,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

According to the documentation, I can [order and limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) my query in order to filter data based on a `where` clause. How can I order this data based on `stats.posts`?

i.e.

```
usersRef.orderBy('stats.posts').limit(15);
```

Comment: `usersRef.orderBy('stats.post').limit(15)` looks right to me. What happens when you try it? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer I was expecting it to be much like a mongoDb query, but any time I use a property it appears to have no effect on result set

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in your code:

```
usersRef.orderBy('stats.post').limit(15);
```

The field name should be `stats.posts` according to your previous structure:

```
usersRef.orderBy('stats.posts').limit(15);
```

I've double checked this works. In the console I created a collection called `tester` that stores 4 documents. Each document has a stats.posts property set to a number 1 through 4. The below code prints out 1, 2, 3. If I remove the limit it prints out 1, 2, 3, 4. If I also remove the order by it prints out 2, 1, 3, 4.

```
db.collection('tester').orderBy('stats.posts').limit(3).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(documentSnapshot) { 
        console.log(documentSnapshot.data().stats.posts);
    });
});
```

Comment: Indeed it is a typo, but it was a made up structure for this question. I've edited the question. The `orderBy` expression appears to have no effect on the query when a property accessor is specified

Comment: you appear to work on the google cloud division. Is this syntax officially supported? I didn't see any examples in the documentation like this.

Comment: I am, I'm the product manager for Cloud Firestore. It is, and I just tested it myself, worked perfectly. If it isn't working for you, you'll need to post more information about what isn't working (e.g errors/output).

Comment: thanks Dan, I had a chance to go through the code and found the ordering was being modified during an angular ng-repeat. The data from the database is properly sorted!

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it sorted!

Comment: I had a similar issue, but mine ended up being a `.where('foo', isEqualTo: true).orderBy('data.time', descending: true)` Which required an index. So while it's not super relevant for this answer, make sure to check your index logs :)